# SQL for comparing 2 tables with multiple columns

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5. There is ability to upgrade it to version 3.x or 4.

I have two different tables in my database:
Table1 Columns: Client_Name, Phone1, Phone 2,...Phone5 (up to 5 phone numbers)
Table2 Columns: Client_Name, Phone1, Phone 2,...Phone7 (up to 7 phone numbers)
Record count of 2 tables is different.

Not all fields are filled in all records - there are many empty filed values, but if phone number is filled in some field, it is "normalized" to 10 digits (varchar). For example, "0681234567".

Most records in Table2 are "similar" to records of Table1. For example, there is a record in Table1 where Phone1 = Phone6 for some record in Table2, or Table1.Phone2=Table2.Phone1, etc.

I need a SQL query that finds "unique" records in Table2 where all phone numbers (Phone1-Phone7) do not exist in any records of Table1 for any of its phone fields (Phone1-Phone5)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs a bit more specificity to be a good fit for this site, see [ask] and [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: you have to resturucture your database, there is to be only one single Phone column in both tables, if you need several phones you have to add a column like `ID integer` and store phones into several rows instead of several columns.  Judging by your name/nation i suggest you to find Шумаков's book (this http://www.ibase.ru/articles/ or previous one for Delphi 3), Delphi specifics can be ignored, but easy introduction into how SQL is different from Excel-like sheets and DBF-like ISAMs would benefit you a lot. Then switch to more in depth Grubber's books, like https://habr.com/ru/post/18362/

Answer (score 0):

The strategy that I would use for this is to have one query which collects all the phone numbers from `Table1` and then use this in a second query to filter the rows from `Table2`.

For the first query you can use the `UNION` operator to convine a query for each column for example `SELECT Phone1 FROM Table1 UNION SELECT Phone2 FROM Table1 UNION ...` then you could use that in a `WITH` block as a subquery and in your main query filter rows like `Phone1 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM all_phone_numbers) AND Phone2 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM all_phone_numbers) AND ...`

Comment: Can you explain better?  Are you looking for records that belong in one but not the other?  Are you looking for elements that belong to both?   If you phrase your question  better you will get better answers.

Comment: `IN` and `NOT IN` are slow in Interbase/Firebird, you would have to use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` instead

Comment: Using CTE gonna be something like `WITH source_sorted as (SELECT Phone1 as Source_Phone FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Phone2 FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Phone3 FROM ...  ORDER BY 1)  SELECT t2.* from Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN source_sorted S1 on S1.Source_Phone = t2.Phone1 LEFT JOIN source_sorted S2 on S2.Source_Phone = t2.Phone2 LEFT JOIN ...  WHERE S1.Source_Phone IS NULL AND S2.Source_Phone IS NULL AND ....`